# Routing error Rails 3.2.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I'm trying to create a very simple site the sends and receives parameters from the URL (or link), the app should support any number of parameters, i.e. http://localhost:3000/action=receive&controller=pages&email=mail%40site.com&name=Vinny, and then be able to receive/print them.

I think I have located the problem to my route. It currently looks like this:

```
match 'pages/*params' => 'pages#receive'
```

I create the link that sends the params like this:

```
<%= link_to "Send Params", :action => "receive", :name => "Vinny", :email => "mail@site.com" %>
```

When I click the link I get the following error.

```
No route matches [GET] "/assets"
```

And the URL looks like this:

http://localhost:3000/assets?action=receive&controller=pages&email=mail%40site.com&name=Vinny

Note **asset?**.

If my route instead looks like this:

```
match 'pages/:name/:email' => 'pages#receive'
```

It works, but then I'm limited to the specified params.

Any tips on how to solve this would be great.

Comment: So hardcoding a route to the 'pages' controller (with params) works even though you're accessing the 'assets' controller?  What if you specifically referenced assets: match 'assets/*params' ...

Comment: @BryanH Hi, no I haven't specified or created a controller called Assets, I only have one controller, Pages. Don't know why Rails adds Assets? to my URL Post. However, I tried to remove `assets?` from the URL and i got another routing problem. I'm pretty rusty with Rails, this might not be the right way to send arbitrary parameters to my controller?

Comment: @BryanH Good idea, but it didn't help. :(

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I think I see what is happening. Specifying parameters in the routes is not necessary to get the values into the controller's action. So, replace the `map` you specified earlier in the `routes.rb` with

```
resources :pages
```

If you add to your link

```
:controller => "pages"
```

It should go to the correct controller + action. (this may not be necessary in your case)

In that action, you can grab all of the params from the hash

```
email = params[:email]
account = params[:name]
```

Etc.

- [Info on routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)
- [Info on params](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#parameters)

Comment: Thanks! Your suggestion works, but it's not completely the result I'm looking for. I probably wasn't clear enough in my original question. What I want is to be able to send arbitrary parameters, your solution only allows the specified(!?!) parameters e.g.. :email. The user should be able to for example add address=NY in the url and the page should print it. Don't know if it's possible the use link_to for that. Might have to use some CGI stuff simple (link_to would be preferable though).

Comment: Thanks for the links, will check them out.

Comment: Ahh I didn't type in all the parameters because I am lazy (hence the "etc"). You can get the value of *any* parameter by `variable = params[:parameter_name]`, where `parameter_name` is the name of the parameter. :)